# Windows 10 update 1 borders too thick and minify/maximize/exit button seperators?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, themes, border

ever since I installed the anniversary update of windows 10, my borders are really thick, and the minify/maximize/close buttons in the top right of a window are seperated by a thin grey line that wraps all around the induvidual buttons, as shown in the image below.

[image]

before the update I had the nice, thin borders and the slick, almost molded together buttons.
I have not installed any kind of software that could change this, and I haven't changed anything, it just was like this since the update.

I tried looking around in the WindowMetrics folder in the registry, and found `borderWidth` but changing that didn't do much, it's also set to -15, which should be 1px, if I'm correct. I didn't find anything for the buttons.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, I found the issue, and I feel stupid.

for some reason, after installing the update, it created a "custom" theme, I didn't realise this. I changed it to the default windows theme and it fixed the issue.

no idea why it did this though.